# Triggered Execution in SBT 0.13.x

Tags: sbt

I am using SBT 0.13.2 and I want to trigger my task by the way of execution of the compile task. I know that I can achieve this by using the `triggeredBy` method, as in `taskDefinition.triggeredBy(compile in Compile)`.

I have a `build.sbt` with my custom task defined.

The problem is that I cannot understand why the following works as expected

```
val triggeredTask = taskKey[Unit]("Triggered by compile")

triggeredTask <<= Def.task {
  println("TRIGGERED BY COMPILE")
}.triggeredBy(compile in Compile)
```

but the next does not work (`compile` executes just fine but my task is not triggered)

```
val triggeredTask = taskKey[Unit]("Triggered by compile")

triggeredTask := Def.task {
  println("TRIGGERED BY COMPILE")
}.triggeredBy(compile in Compile).value
```

My understanding was that SBT 0.13 made `<<=` obsolete and `:=` should be sufficient.

Comment: I believe this is a legit bug.  I haven't been able to get it to work with triggers either unless using << syntax (due to how tagging works).

Answer (score 1):

I might misunderstand what you are trying to do.

If I make your example more verbose it becomes like this:

```
val triggeredTaskKey = taskKey[Unit]("Triggered by compile")

val anonymousTask = Def.task {
  println("TRIGGERED BY COMPILE")
}.triggeredBy(compile in Compile)

// I imagine the macro doing something like this
triggeredTaskKey <<= anonymousTask map (identity)
```

This also does not trigger the anonymous task on `compile`.

Note that `<<=` is a gloried version of `set` that extracts position information. And `set` is simply an alias for `Def.setting(key, value, position)` which in turn creates a new `Setting` instance. Note that the setting instance that is created internally has a constructor of those 3 parameters.

I do not think there is a way in sbt to declare a setting without a key (I might be wrong here). It seems however that you want to create a setting (that is triggered) without a key.

This might be caused by a bug, I am not sure if sbt should recursively walk the dependencies to find tasks that have a `triggeredBy` key in their `info`. It currently however is not (as seen in the [`trigger` method](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13.6/main/src/main/scala/sbt/EvaluateConfigurations.scala#L282).

Theoretically you could make a work around that creates settings with the correct triggers bound to some arbitrary key. I am not sure how that would work.

Comment: I think this was a bug (not sure if fixed or not now). jsureth mentioned that in a comment to the original question. The problem is not a workaround, because one of the examples works. I was just curious about the one which doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is centered on SBT `0.13.x`, but in case there's still confusion for SBT `1.3.4` [this example](https://binx.io/blog/2018/12/08/the-scala-build-tool/#dependency-key-operator) works and does a good job [addressing the v0.x bug](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1444):

```scala
lazy val task1 = taskKey[Unit]("task 1")
lazy val task2 = taskKey[Unit]("task 2")

task1 := println("Task 1")
task2 := println("Task 2")

task2 := (task2 triggeredBy task1).value
```

So typing `task1` should print both "Task 1" and "Task 2". And of course you can `triggeredBy compile.In(Compile)` instead of a custom `taskKey` like "task1"