# Play Framework 2.3.4: How to Run JSHint as a Part of the Compile Task

Tags: playframework, sbt, jshint

I've a multi-project application and I want to make `JSHint` run as a part of the compile task. Here below is how I configured my project:

1) Added the JSHint plugin to `myApp/project/plugins.sbt`:

```
...

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")
```

2) Enabed it (SbtWeb) in `myApp/build.sbt`:

```
...

lazy val apidocs = project.in(file("modules/apidocs")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala, SbtWeb).settings(
  javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=apidocs-application.conf"
).dependsOn(
  common % "test->test;compile->compile"
)
```

I've also tried to run the `assets` task... but it looks like JSHint don't get invoked. How can I make JSHint run as a part of the compile task? Maybe an even better option would be to modify `myApp/projects/Build.scala` and let JSHint compress any `*.js` in any subproject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'm assuming you're using [this version of sbt-jshint](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jshint) (there seem to be at least 3 popular versions floating around).

The general gist of this is that we need to have a task that is triggered by compilation. This is pretty easily adaptable from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26476160/1808164). So we add the following to `build.sbt`:

```
val triggeredTask = taskKey[Seq[sbt.File]]("Triggered by compile")

triggeredTask <<= Def.task {
  JshintKeys.jshint.value
}.triggeredBy(compile in Compile)
```

Things to note here are that the `taskKey` Type is not unit like the answer I linked to, but the type of the jshint task. Second thing to note here is the weirdness of referencing jshint. `JshintKeys.jshint` versus just calling jshint. I kept getting a "error: not found: value jshint" until I did this. If you look in the [source](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jshint/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/jshint/SbtJSHint.scala#L12) you'll see that JshintKeys is an object inside an object. I don't know if that's standard for writing sbt plugins, but I know it makes this neccesary. Last, the `.value` is how we say that our triggered task depends on another task.

Once you have that in place, you should see the compilation step trigger jshint :)

Answer (score 0):

JShint doesn't compress anything, It detects and warns about bad practices in your JavaScripts.

From the docs of the plugin (and the sources) it does not seem that the linting task is run automatically, it just provides the task "jshint" which you could call in your sbt console to get a the jshint result output.

You could probably integrate it with the compile task of your project(s) to get it to fail when there are linting warnings, cant tell you exactly how from the top of my head though, I would recommend you to become better friends with sbt to figure that one out. (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html)